# Articulate Storyline 2 won't install

Tags: windows

I'm trying to install Articulate Storyline 2 on my Lenovo G400s Touch laptop running Windows 10 64-bit but I keep getting the message "Install Failed. The Storyline installation folder contents appear to have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Error: 80070643".

Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View installed updates
- Remove the Windows update KB2918614
- Restart PC and install Storyline 2 again